# Mxf DNxHD (Op-Atom) with ffmepg, problem with Da vinci resolve

Tags: ffmpeg, mxf

I'am using ffmpeg to convert many video in .Mxf "Op Atom DNxHD 36"

If I export the file from davinci and try to reopen it with davinci, I can import it.
If I export the file with ffmpeg I can't import it into davinci.

i use this in ffmpeg:

```
 ffmpeg -i $inputFile -c:v dnxhd -f mxf_opatom -an -vf "scale=1920x1080,fps=25/1,format=yuv422p" -b:v 36M -an $outputFile
```